# Is it OK to ask question seeking list of places offering negatives to digital conversion?

Tags: discussion

I have some photos (prints and negatives) that I want to convert to digital so I'm looking for services that offer good negatives to digital conversion.

To avoid making my question too localized (and also because I travel and will appreciate having choices where I am), I'm thinking of posting a question that seeks listing by countries. Is this OK for this site? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List-type questions are not a good fit for our forum. They invite endless input of information that can and often does constantly evolve, thus mitigating or negating the value for other readers.

The best kinds of questions for PhotoSE are ones that have definitive answers that can actually be accepted as such. Open-ended questions that simply ask for lists of things really don't belong here. You are probably better off asking your question on a standard forum dedicated to photography, where the resident forum goers have the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Thought I'll ask first instead of creating more work for moderators.

Comment: As an aside, It's generally the wider community that would vote to close, either as something like "not constructive" or "too localised" for those sorts of questions.